# How not to strip leading zero in advanced custom fields

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I have custom field for phone number but the leading zero is not saved in db

I tried to format the field as number and text but the zero is not showing

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just make the field type as text and it will work

Comment: But you wrote in your question that you've done that and it didn't work.

Comment: Its working now